# Can I copy a file to iCloud drive from the command line?

Tags: icloud, command-line

I'd like to write a script to backup some files to my iCloud drive. The drive shows up in the Finder, but I don't see it from the command line.  Is there a way to do something like:

> cp mystuff.tgz /iCloudDrive/backups/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iCloud Drive** directory is located here:

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
```

There are some other directories listed inside `Mobile Documents`, their names depend on the app which owns them. For example: `com~apple~Pages/`.